# Having trouble finding the recursive relation.

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am give $s_n = 2^n + 3^n + 4^n$ for $n = 1,2,...$

so far I have

n = 1 : 2 + 3 + 4 = 9

n = 2 : 4 + 9 + 16 = 29

n = 3 : 8 + 27 + 64 = 99

n = 4 : 16 + 81 + 256 = 353

I am having a hard time trying to figure out the pattern.

Comment: The pattern is that they are $2^n+3^n+4^n$. Do you need something more than that, and if so what?

Comment: I need to find the recursive relation that satisfies $s_n = 2^n + 3^n +4^n$

Comment: Well, I think the question is asking for $s_n$ as a function of preceding terms?

Comment: $s_n = s_{n-1} + 2^{n-1} + 2 \cdot 3^{n-1} + 3 \cdot 4^{n-1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristic equation must be
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)=0. \\
\end{eqnarray*}
So the recurrence relation must be
\begin{eqnarray*}
\color{blue}{s_{n+3}-9s_{n+2}+26s_{n+1}-24s_n=0}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}